# How to open a csv file in another directory from a HTML file

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to Django. This is my project structure[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DulJS.png)

When I render the table.html file in the templates folder, in the html file I want to access the tomsim_FruitDev.csv file in the output folder.

````
      ```
         <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $.ajax({
           url:"output/tomsim_FruitDev.csv",
           dataType:"text",
           success:function(data)
           {
             var radiation_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
             var table_data = '<table class="table table-hover">';
          for(var count = 0; count<radiation_data.length; count++)
            {
              var cell_data = radiation_data[count].split(",");
              table_data += '<tr>';
              for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
              {
               if(count === 0)
               {
                table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
                }
               else
              {
               table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
              }
            }
             table_data += '</tr>';
           }
           table_data += '</table>';
           $('#datatable').html(table_data);
         }
       });
      });
      </script>
````

I keep getting this error http://localhost:8000/output/tomsim_FruitDev.csv 404 (Not Found)>. How can I make my application to look into the output folder.
    I tried editing my settings.py file. I am not sure where to add the path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because of url

```
url:"output/tomsim_FruitDev.csv",
```

First you need to setup your settings for static content.

[Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

Now you have 2 methods to render your .CSV file.

1. Render your .CSV file into template on server and get back
   response using AJAX.You can use render_to_string method.
2. Fetch File using AJAX.

---

**How To configure using 2nd method**

In settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT  = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/files/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

]

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/media/' # actual media directory   
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # URL which is display
```

In root urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

---

Create media directory in your root directory. 
Place your file in media folder.

```
 url: "{{MEDIA_URL}}file.csv",
```

That's it.